# How to pass concatenated value of drop down to stored proc as parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down where in the values are concatenated from two columns of a table, now I will use the value of that drop down as a parameter to another stored procedure, is this possible? How will I do that?

This is my code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reassign]
   @recordumber int
   @employeeName
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE QR
    SET QR.QAMemberID = @QAMemberID
    FROM Roster AS QR
    INNER JOIN TeamMaster S TM 
       ON QR.QAMemberID = TM.QAMemberID
    WHERE QR.recordNumber = @recordumber
      and qr.firstname, qr.lastname = @employeeName
END
```

and `qr.firstname`, `qr.lastname = @employeeName` I know this last piece of code is wrong... how can I do this the right way? Thank you...

Comment: People will tend to answer your questions better if you show what you have tried. Post some code that isn't working so we can point you in the right direction - otherwise we have to charge you by the hour to write it for you

Comment: thanks.. its my first time :), code is now added

Comment: you can use qr.firstname + ' ' + qr.lastname = @employeeName if you concatenated that fields with space. But it's better to pass two parameters into the procedure

Comment: Is `RecordNumber` an identity column?  If so, you should just use that and not also use `@employeeName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not concatenate the values together in your code, but rather use a parameter for `firstName` and a parameter for `lastName`, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reassign]
    @recordumber int,
    @firstName,
    @lastName
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE QR
    SET QR.QAMemberID = @QAMemberID
    FROM Roster AS QR
    INNER JOIN TeamMaster S TM 
        ON QR.QAMemberID = TM.QAMemberID
    WHERE QR.recordNumber = @recordumber
        and qr.firstname = @firstName, qr.lastname = @lastName
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the value from your drop down you can use this in the code behind

```
 if (myDropDown.SelectedIndex != 0) 
 {
     var myData = myDropDown.SelectedValue;

     // access Sproc and you can then pass myData


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qr.firstname + ' ' + qr.lastname = @employeeName` if you concatenated that fields with space.

```
...
  and qr.firstname + ' ' + qr.lastname = @employeeName
...
```

But it's better to pass two parameters into the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reassign]
   @recordumber int
   @firstname,
   @lastname
AS
...
  and qr.firstname = @firstname and qr.lastname = @lastname
...
```